# Unable to build ResponseEntity inside flatMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-rest

I am trying to convert ClientResponse to ResponseEntity inside the flatMap method but it returns an error.

Code:

```java
Mono<ResponseEntity> response = 
           webClient.post()
                    .uri(requestURI)
                    .exchange()
                    .flatMap(clientResponse -> {

                        ResModel rm = new ResModel();
                        // call setter methods on rm
                        return ResponseEntity.ok(rm);
                    });
```

This throws the error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity conforms to reactor.core.publisher.Mono)

I don't understand why this error occurs. I also tried to return a modified `ClientResponse` after building it but received similar error.

I am pretty new to Spring and have already spent nearly 2 days on this error. 
I also tried using `flatMapMany` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332137 but get same error.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this and why this occurs

Comment: _"I am pretty new to Spring"_ - this has nothing to do with Spring. You need to learn how and when to use `flatMap`.

Comment: @Kartik If you know where I am wrong, then please tell.

Comment: I have no idea about webflux yet. But 2 things I can point out here:
1. you are returning a type of ResponseEntity, but trying to typecast into Mono. I am not sure if these are compatible.
2. You need to return a single object, but flatMap would return a Stream, again incompatible. See this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Ah. That solved it. Had to use map instead of flatMap. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: `ResponseEntity` is also generic.